# Storing and retrieving a complex type in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an `Object` which is an `ObservableCollection<T>`. `Type T` has `int`, `string`, `bool`, `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, `Visibility` and `ObservableCollection` objects.

What is the best way to store my `T` object as the app closes, then retrieve it when the app is opened again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use `DataContract` and `DataContractSerializer`

Let's create our serializable class

```
    public class MySerializableObject
    {

         public int age {get; set;}

         public string name {get; set;}

         public bool isAwesome {get; set;}

    }
```

This class the way it is won't serialize. We need to add some attributes in to make it work.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MySerializableObject
    {

          [DataMember]
          public int age {get; set;}
          [DataMember]
          public string name {get; set;}
          [DataMember]
          public bool isAwesome {get; set;}

    }
```

Now that we have added in `DataContract` above the class and `DataMember` above our properties, they will be serializable.

Then you can use `DataContractSerializer` to serialize or deserialize your data

The below code is out of my personal library. It works.

```
    public static void SaveObject(SerializeableObject value)
    {
        Serialize(value, new FileStream(ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path 
            + @"\" + value.objectName + ".russ", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
    }

    public static Object GetObject(string objectName, Type targetType)
    {
        return Deserialize(new FileStream(ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path
           + @"\" + objectName + ".russ", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), targetType);
    }

    private static void Serialize(SerializeableObject objectToSerialize, FileStream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = objectToSerialize.GetSerializer();
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, objectToSerialize);
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to Serialize");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static Object Deserialize(FileStream stream, Type targetType)
    {
        Object returnValue = null;
        try
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer =
                  new DataContractSerializer(targetType);

            stream.Position = 0;
            returnValue = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to Deserialize");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here are the objects I am using in the above code

```
    [DataContract]
    public class TestSave : SerializeableObject
    {        
        [DataMember]
        public string objectName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public bool SaveTestProp { get; set; }

        public DataContractSerializer GetSerializer()
        {
            return new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TestSave));
        }
    }

    public interface SerializeableObject
    {
        string objectName { get; }
        DataContractSerializer GetSerializer();
    }
```

Comment: Will [DataMember] work even if it's a complex property? As I have said, there is another ObservableCollection inside type T, a Visibility and a PropertyChangedEventHandler.

Comment: Make those object's members serializable too and it will work

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos please look at my updated answer. It's now compiled and tested.

Comment: I had to make some changes to the code to fit my needs, but you showed me the right direction to solving the problem. :^)